# How to remove the Horzontal Scroll bars in tables in the Ag-Grid in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am new to Ag-Grid React, I have created the table but by default, there are Horizontal Scroll bars at the bottom. Can anyone tell me how to remove them in AgGridReact?

---

```
export default class test extends Component {
    state={
        rowData:null,
        columnDefs:[
            {headerName: 'ID', field:'ID'},
            {headerName: 'request', field:'request'},
            {headerName: 'block', field:'block'},
            {headerName: 'chainCode', field:'ID'},
            {headerName: 'event', field:'event'},
        ]
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const res = await axios.get('api')
        this.setState({rowData:res.data})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='ag-theme-alpine' 
            style={{
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
            }}>
                <AgGridReact 
                columnDefs= {this.state.columnDefs}
                rowData={this.state.rowData}
                />
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Cam you provide a snippet or whatever you tried so far?

Comment: You can add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the element with the Horizontal Scroll bars.

Comment: ya sure, i will in a bit